# How to use angular routing for directly access to content

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

how can i use Angular routing  to access clickable content ( appears when click on a specific tab) when insert  URL directly in browser?
for example I have a menu when i click on first tab  some content apear and when click on another tab show something else  and url was change but when I insert that url directly in the address bar, the content does not show. how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a 404 when putting the url directly in the browser address bar?

If so, it sounds like you need to configure your web server to route all requests to the page AngularJS loads from. AngularJS routing will then take over and load the content as expected.

Comment: no it doesnt its load index.html content, i don't use virtual host for example wamp or lamp

Comment: What backend technologies are you using?  (ie, PHP, Node, Ruby etc...)